# Removing duplicates from arraylist which contain array of double

Tags: c#, arraylist, duplicates

I have a list which has double array whose items are geocordinates,this list has duplicate elements which i need to remove to preserve only unique values

this is what i have tried

```
IList<double[]> result = new List<double[]>(); /list declaration

// result gets value from a soap call 

for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < result.Count; j++)
    {
         if (result[i][0].ToString() == result[j][0].ToString() || result[i][1].ToString() == result[j][1].ToString())
         {
             result.Remove(result[j]);
         }
    }
}
```

result - my list which has redundant arrays

basically, i need to remove all the arrays inside the list which has same values(x and y geocordinates)

still i have some elements in the list which gets duplicated, can anyone improve my solution please ?
would be great help

Comment: same geocordinates means both x and y must be equal so change `||` to `&&`

Comment: doesnt work,still i have duplicates present

Comment: Create an array; then save data that has their condition and finally, replace the new array with Old Array.

Comment: sorry didnt get you,can u please edit the code and help ?

Comment: _my implementation doesnt work well_ This is not a helpful problem description. Also. ArrayList is basically deprecated. Use List<T> instead. Also: In Linq there are function to make lists unique..

Comment: sorry,im a java dev..i use List<T> itself..i have used distinct() method of linq but i guess it doesnt work for the elements of array in the list.

Comment: It should, when done right. do you use `double` or`float`  ? (`decimal` is recommended esp.. if any computation is involved). Do show the definitions of your variables!

Comment: edited the question,please have a look at it

Comment: Your inner loop should start from i+1 th element

Comment: that doesnt make any difference though,still duplicates are present

Comment: Even if you find the right solution for your question, I would recommend to change your approach. Instead of using `double[]`, you can define coordinates as Point class. In `Point` class, you can override the `ToEquals` method to check the duplicate.

Comment: After you remove an element, you will have to decrement j so that you process all the elements.  Check my answer to see if it works.

Comment: @user1672994 : A good idea, at least if Point is a <decimal, decimal>

Comment: Instead of using existing Point from `System.Windows` or `System.Drawing`, I would suggest to write a new class with decimal and decimal as X and Y respectively. With this approach, you will have full control over it to override ToEquals method.

Comment: Or you can also use `GeoCoordinate` from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Iterate result backwards. If you find a duplicate you end up skipping the next item in the list since the list has now been shifted by one index. That value might be a dupe, but you'd ignore it.

Comment: Also why using strings to compare? While true that tou shouldn't compare doubles for direct equality (usually using an epsilon value), depending on your values ToString may not give you a valid representation for comparison either. At least specify a number format so things are consistent.. Or use a framework class like others suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
result = result.GroupBy(r => new { val1 = r[0], val2 = r[1] })
               .Select(g => new double[] { g.Key.val1, g.Key.val2 }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

This example takes the 100 in `data` down to 41 in `dataUnique`

```
Random r = new Random(99);
var data = new List<Tuple<decimal, decimal>>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    data.Add(new Tuple<decimal, decimal>(r.Next(7)/100m, r.Next(7)/100m));
}
var dataUnique = data.Distinct().ToList();
```

Wrt your code: Do note that comparing `float` or `double` will not work well if **any** computation has been used on those numbers as binary numbers do not allow the precision needed to do the comparisons.. - Do replace the `double` by `decimal` as a first improvement..

Using `ToString()` may or may not help overcome the issue; best not to rely on it..

Answer (score 1):

```
IList<double[]> result = new List<double[]>(); /list declaration

// result gets value from a soap call 

for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < result.Count; j++)
    {
         if (result[i][0].ToString() == result[j][0].ToString() && result[i][1].ToString() == result[j][1].ToString())
         {
             result.Remove(result[j]);
             j--;
         }
    }
}
```